# Multithreading implementation using python does not work

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to process multiple lists using multiprocessing. i have implemented this way. but its not working. could somebody help on this?
main_list has one iteration,

> range(len(np_optimization))

using this iterating again, i thing due to this multiprocessing not working.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import numpy as np
pt = ThreadPool(mp.cpu_count() - 2)

def test_code(args):
    idx, pld_idx, number, dimention, quantity, orientation, matrix, np_optimization = \
    args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5], args[6], args[7]
    position = False
    lwh = (228.0, 139.2, 127.6)
    for idx in range(len(np_optimization)):
        b1_l, b1_w, b1_h = dimention[np_optimization[idx][1][0]][0], \
        dimention[np_optimization[idx][1][0]][1], dimention[np_optimization[idx][1][0]][2]
        b1_dim = (b1_l, b1_w, b1_h)
        b2_l, b2_w, b2_h = dimention[np_optimization[idx][1][1]][0], \
        dimention[np_optimization[idx][1][1]][1], dimention[np_optimization[idx][1][1]][2]
        b2_dim = (b2_l, b2_w, b2_h)
        block_combination_dim = np.array((b1_dim, b2_dim))
        block_dim_sum = block_combination_dim.dot(matrix).sum(axis=0)
        dim_fit_check = (block_dim_sum < lwh).astype(int)
        fit_result = np.any(dim_fit_check)
        if fit_result:
            position = np.zeros_like(dim_fit_check)
            position[np.argmax(dim_fit_check == 1)] = 1
            break
    if position is False:
        quant = []
        info = "Single"
    else:
        quant = np_optimization[idx][0]
        b1_block_dim = (...)
        b2_block_dim = (...)
        info = ([b1_block_dim, b2_block_dim, list(position)])
    return quant, info


main_list = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21], 0, array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]), array([[168. ,  94. ,  30.5],
       [168. ,  94. ,  61. ],
       [168. ,  94. ,  91.5],
       [168. ,  94. , 122. ],
       [168. ,  30.5,  94. ],
       [168. ,  61. ,  94. ],
       [168. ,  91.5,  94. ],
       [168. , 122. ,  94. ]]), array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array(['LxWxH', 'LxWxH', 'LxWxH', 'LxWxH', 'LxHxW', 'LxHxW', 'LxHxW',
       'LxHxW'], dtype='<U5'), array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]]), [(8, (3, 7)), (8, (6, 6)), (7, (2, 5)), (7, (3, 3)), (7, (3, 6))]]

def test():
    for i in range(3):
        # pld_idx = i
        # constructing all the lists here.
        output = pt.map(test_code, main_list)
        print(output)
```

Comment: could you give an example about how to use your code now? and what you wish to change in your question,  it's quite difficult for other people to understand your code and help you

Comment: `test_code` appears to be a method of a class. Not knowing how the class is defined or what the method's argument types are, it is very difficult to provide an answer. I can tell you that this method has far too many redundant expressions,  for example `dimension[np_optimization[idx][1][0]]`, and could be greatly simplified for readability as well as performance.

Comment: thanks Booboo. i have updated my post with the test data.

Comment: "multiprocessing not working" — why do you think so? If you do not see multiple processor loads try `from multiprocessing import Pool`. Threads are not that parallel in Python.

Comment: There is no code that invokes `test`. Your code has numerous errors that prevent it from running, for example `mp.cpu_count()` and `array` are not defined. When you fix those put a try/except around  the body of `test_code` to see the numerous exceptions that are raised. First try running code that uses neither multithreading nor multiprocessing and get that to work before you take the next step..